# Strange Value in EXE header

Tags: windows, portable-executable, executable-format

I've seen a strange value placed in an EXE header

```
00000000 :4D 5A 90 00 03 00 00 00 - 04 00 00 00 FF FF 00 00
00000010 :B8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00000020 :00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00000030 :00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 A8 00 00 00 <-
```

I don't know what `A8` is doing at offset 3C but if I replace it with zeros my program doesn't execute.

What is that?

Could you give me a hyperlink to the full MS DOS header (spec)?

Comment: Why are you mucking around with program headers?  It might help if we understood why you care what's in there.  Also what platform is this?

Comment: Here's a document that may help you: http://www.thehackerslibrary.com/?p=377

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DWORD at offset 0x3c is the offset of the new EXE header, aka IMAGE_NT_HEADERS. So if you change the value there, the PE loader cannot find the new EXE header.

Comment: I think Matteo Italia gave the link in his answer: http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/platform/firmware/PECOFFdwn.mspx.

Answer (score 4):

The first part of a PE is the MSDOS stub; at 0x3C (where your "A8" is) there's the offset to the PE file signature. If you zero it, the loader won't be able to find the PE signature, and will refuse to load it (or load it as just an MS-DOS executable, I didn't try).
For more information, see the [PE format specifications](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/platform/firmware/PECOFFdwn.mspx).

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that it is the offset to the new PE header, the first 30 odd bytes are the MS-DOS header, that offset into the file where 0xA8 resides in corresponds to the field in the structure `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER` called

```
LONG e_lfanew;  // File address of new exe header
```

It is that value 0xA8 would be part of the new `IMAGE_NT_HEADER` which contains this information:

1. `DWORD Signature;`
2. `IMAGE_FILE_HEADER FileHeader;`
3. `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER OptionalHeader;`

The very first two bytes are the original MS-DOS header into the executable as shown by this constant:

```
WORD IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE = 0x5A4D;      // MZ
```

The IMAGE_NT_HEADER has this signature to identify that it is an executable for NT platforms

```
DWORD IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE = 0x00004550;   // PE00
```

You will find all this information in a header file called `pe.h`.

What happened there is you wiped out the value 0xA8, the loader could not find the `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` and hence failed.